# Need one digit after decimal without changing any number

Tags: php

I have a value 3.9609053497942. I need value 3.9 means only one value after decimal. I have used PHP number_format and round functions but it is giving me answer 4.

Comment: Show your code with number_fromat

Comment: echo number_format(3.9609053497942,1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this,

```
echo intval((3.9609053497942*10))/10;
```

or

```
echo floor((3.9609053497942*10))/10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could multiply the number by 10, `floor()` it, and then divide it back.

```
echo floor($value * 10) / 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so many possible solutions:

```
echo bcadd(3.9609053497942, 0, 1);

preg_match('/\d*\.\d/', 3.9609053497942, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

why not treat it as a string, like

```
$x = (string)3.96;
$y = explode(".",$x);
$result = $y[0] . "." . $y[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried like:

> number_format(3.9609053497942, 1);

Comment: Yes it is not working. it is giving answer 4.0 but i need 3.9 answer